# How to convert a pdf file to an image?

Tags: android, image, pdf

I'm trying to use the ML Kit Text Recognition API in my android app. However it doesn't work with a PDF, I need an image. So I'm looking for a way to convert PDF to image.

I have already try several solutions but most of them are not working anymore.

Note: The PDF file is picked on the device with a file picker

```
private void extractText2(Uri uri) {
    try {
        Log.e("URI", uri.toString());
        FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromFilePath(getApplicationContext(), uri);
        FirebaseVisionTextRecognizer detector = FirebaseVision.getInstance().getOnDeviceTextRecognizer();

        Task<FirebaseVisionText> result =
                detector.processImage(image)
                        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<FirebaseVisionText>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(FirebaseVisionText firebaseVisionText) {
                                displayText(firebaseVisionText);
                            }
                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(
                                new OnFailureListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                        // Task failed with an exception
                                        // ...
                                    }
                                });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Erreur", e.getMessage());
    }
}

private void displayText(FirebaseVisionText result) {
    String resultText = result.getText();
    Log.e("Text trouvé:",resultText);
}

public void performFileSearch() {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
    intent.setType("image/*");
    startActivityForResult(intent, READ_REQUEST_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
                             Intent resultData) {

    if (requestCode == READ_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri uri;
        if (resultData != null) {
            uri = resultData.getData();
            Log.i("---", "Uri: " + uri.toString());
            extractText2(uri);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code allows to pick an image, then the text recognition work well. If I want to pick a pdf, I have to replace intent.setType("image/*"); with intent.setType("application/pdf"); but the text recognition API won't work, that's why i need to convert the pdf file choosen to an image and then use the text recognition

Comment: why would you use a Text recognition tool to read pdf ?

Comment: What have yougot so far ? If post your code,it would be easy to help

Comment: Because the text in the pdf is in an image, I can not copy it for instance